# $\textstyle\displaystyle{\sum_{a_1,\dots, a_n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}}=n!\zeta(n+1)$

Tags: solution-verification

### $\underline{\text{Motivation}:-}$

Recently I saw [this video](https://youtu.be/5KpGSMyUANU) from Micheal Penn. After seeing the entire video I realized that all the things he did can be easily generalized.

In that video he showed,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\sum_{m,n\ge 1}\frac{1}{mn(m+n)}=2\zeta(3)}$

So this is my motivation.

### $\underline{\text{My work}:-}$

$■Claim:-$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\sum_{a_1,\dots, a_n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}}=n!\zeta(n+1)$

$■Proof:-$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\sum_{a_1,\dots, a_n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}}$

$=\sum_{a_1=1}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{a_n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_1\cdots a_n(a_1+\cdots+a_n)}$

Now we use the fact that $\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1}dx}$

So we get,

$\sum_{a_1=1}^{\infty}\cdots\sum_{a_n=1}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{1}x_1^{a_1-1}dx_1\cdots\int_{0}^{1}x_n^{a_n-1}dx_n\int_{0}^{1}y^{a_1+\cdots+a_n-1}dy\right)$

$=\int\cdots\int_{[0,1]^{n+1}}y^{n-1}\left(\sum_{a_1=1}^{\infty}x_1^{a_1-1}y^{a_1-1}\cdots\sum_{a_n=1}^{\infty}x_n^{a_n-1}y^{a_n-1}\right)dx_1\cdots dx_ndy$

Next we use the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$

Giving us,

$\int\cdots\int_{[0,1]^{n+1}}\frac{y^{n-1}}{(1-x_1y)\cdots(1-x_ny)}dx_1\cdots dx_ndy$

$=\int_{0}^{1}y^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1-x_1y}dx_kdy$

$=\int_{0}^{1}y^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(-\frac{\ln(1-x_ky)}{y}\bigg|_{0}^{1})dy$

$=(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^n(1-y)}{y}dy$

Substituting $z=1-y$ gives us,

$(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^n(z)}{1-z}dz$

$=(-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}z^k\ln^n(z)dz$

Substituting $u=-\ln(z)$ gives us,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^ne^{-(k+1)u}du$

Finally substituting $t=(k+1)u$ gives us,

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^ne^{-t}dt$

$=n!\zeta(n+1)$

$\therefore\textstyle\displaystyle{\sum_{a_1,\dots, a_n\geq 1}\frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}}=n!\zeta(n+1)$

There is another way, if we take

$(-1)^n\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^n(z)}{1-z}dz$

And instead turning it into a sum. We just substitute $u=-\ln(z)$ then we get,

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^n}{e^u-1}du=\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1)$

And since $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ we can write it as

$n!\zeta(n+1)$

### $\underline{\text{My Question}:-}$

I would like to have my proof reviewed. But I am really asking for better ways to derive this.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to align text side by side (right to left)?

Comment: This formula is known, see page 369 in L. J. Mordell (1958) On the evaluation of some multiple series. *J. London Math. Soc.* (2) **33**, pp. 368–371.

Comment: @Gary. So what do I do now? Delete this question?

Comment: It is up to you I guess.

Comment: @Gary. I won't delete it. How many books do you read? Like who even reads a book from 1958?

Comment: This is a paper and not a book. As time passes you build up a knowledge, you remember results or how to find them in the literature. In this case, I knew I saw it in the DLMF: http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.6.E5 and the DLMF refers to Mordell's paper.

Comment: A simplification: it is sufficient to use your $\frac1r=\int_0^1 x^{r-1}\,dx$ (fix the typo btw) for $r=a_1+\dots+a_n$ **only**. This leads to the final (single) logarithmic integral immediately.

Comment: @metamorphy. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: Chalk it up as a character-building exercise.

Comment: @A rural reader. Wait what?